# Trying to read a text Excel cell with Java Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to read an Excel cell that may have the following formats:

```
087
098
057
044
```

I'm trying to make the following:

```
workbookSheet.getRow(row).getCell(columnItemId.getIndex()).setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
String cell = workbookSheet.getRow(row).getCell(columnItemId.getIndex())
                            .getStringCellValue();
```

The problem is that I get the number without the zero, for example 87 instead of 087.

Does anyone have solved something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value retrieved from the numeric cell is numeric, a `double`, which doesn't have any formatting information such as leading zeroes.  The `getStringCellValue` method converts the `double` to a `String`, but it never had the leading zero from the display.

To get a string that represents how the cell is formatted in Excel, you can use Apache POI's [`DataFormatter`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) class.

```
DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
String text = df.formatCellValue(cell);
```

This should get you the string value as Excel renders it in the cell, according to the formatting present on the cell.